# Diferencias entre métodos

Tags: c++, método

Algunos usan el `system("PAUSE")`, otros el `getch()` y también he visto que se puede usar el `cin.get()`.

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre estos 3 "métodos" o como se llamen (agradecería que me digan a qué categoría pertenecen estos 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un [método](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_(inform%C3%A1tica)) es una función de un objeto. Así que de lo mencionado sólo `get()` (de [`std::basic_istream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)) es un método, el resto son funciones.

---

[`system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) es una función que le pide al sistema operativo que ejecute un comando. En tu ejemplo, muy probablemente se trate de la consola de Windows llamando al comando [`pause`](http://www.windowscommandline.com/pause/).

[`getc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgetc) es una función que lee un solo carácter de un archivo.

[`cin.get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) es un método de un flujo de entrada de datos que lee un solo carácter, dado que se usa sobre la instancia de la entrada de consola [`cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) (`c`onsole `in`put), el programa se quedará a la espera de que se introduzcan datos (entendiendo introducir datos no como pulsar una tecla si no como validar los datos entrados mediante <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Comment: añadiría, en el caso de `cin.get`, que el sistema se quedará esperando a que se introduzca un *enter* independientemente de que el método te devuelva únicamente un caracter